# app-ads.txt verification of Facebook app fails

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to add the iOS platform to my Facebook app. Under Settings > Basic > Add platform > iOS, I added:

1. Bundle id
2. The iPhone and iPad store ids (which I believe are the Apple ids of
   my iOS app)
3. My shared secret

I then uploaded the `app-ads.txt` to my domain, for which I tried all of the following versions.
(Each line represents the sole content of the .txt in each try)
(For each version I also tried `RESELLER` instead of `DIRECT`)

`facebook.com, <my_facebook_app_id>, DIRECT, c3e20eee3f780d68`

`facebook.com, <my_ios_app_apple_id>, DIRECT, c3e20eee3f780d68`

`apple.com, <my_ios_app_apple_id>, DIRECT`

`<url_to_my_app_store_presence>, <my_ios_app_apple_id>, DIRECT`

All of these give the following error message:

```
Error(s) found while validating app-ads.txt. Please select Confirm ownership for more details.
```

I am trying to follow these guides:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/release/mobile-app-verification
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/optimization/best-practices/troubleshoot-app-ads

[image]

Comment: So what details did you get shown then, after doing what the error message said?

Comment: It‘s just the same, I click on „Confirm Ownership“ and then it returns the same error message :(

Comment: Check if https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ can read your app-ads.txt URL. (Since this is the Open Graph debugger, it will give you errors regarding that then, but it is a good way to test if Facebook can connect to a URL in general at least.)

Comment: Yes it can, like you said with a warning regarding missing `og:image`

Comment: @TonaldDrump did it work? I've been in the same situation for 3 days

Comment: Which app ID did it end up needing to be? Facebook App Id? iTunes App ID? The facebook documentation isn't clear

Comment: What did you use for the Certificate Authority ID?

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem for a few days. Here's the solution I finally found in the [Facebook Developer Forums](https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/3169093430074033/):

Go to Monetization Manager, then Integrations, then to Properties. Click on "Create property", choose create new property, add your game's name, then click Create. On the next step, choose Android, put your game's url, then on payment choose your account and the next step should be verification - which is the same as on app's page, with app-ads.txt but it works.

After that go back to basic settings and click confirm ownership and it goes through.

Comment: I was not signed up for the Monetization Manage, so I didn't try it. But it did work after a couple of days. From the Facbeook Dev forum a lot of people were having the same issue. I think Facbeook finally came around fixing it :)